# Angular - How to test redirection with $routeChangeStart

Tags: angularjs

I added a system which tests each time URL changes whether the user is not logged in and if so, redirects to the login page.

I have a test that fails since I added some new code.

Code :

```
app.run(function($rootScope, userService, authService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
        if (!userService.isLoggedIn()) {
            authService.login();
            return;
        }
    })
});
```

Test :

```
describe('profile module', function() {
    var $scope, $location;    
    beforeEach(module('app'));    
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $location = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', [ 'path' ]);
        $controller('ProfileCtrl', {
            $scope : $scope,
            $location : $location
        });
    }));

    it('should logout and redirect to login page when disconnect', inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $scope.disconnect();
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/logout').respond(200);
        $httpBackend.flush();
        // Not works since new code !
        expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');
    }));
});
```

Test output :

```
    .........................
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) profile module should logout and redirect to login page when disconnect FAILED
        Expected spy $location.path to have been called with [ '/login' ] but it was never called.
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 26 of 26 (1 FAILED) (0.069 secs / 0.325 secs)
    Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I don't understand the problem.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does $scope.disconnect() do ? You could just broadcast the $routeChangeStart event inside the test after you've called disconnect.

Comment: disconnect does : localStorageService.clearAll();$http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: '/logout'
         }); $location.path('/login');

Comment: I added $rootScope.$broadcast("$routeChangeStart"); in test before expect(). but same message.